# How remove variables to a certain number from Cronbach's Alpha?

Tags: reliability

I'm looking to use Cronbach's Alpha for one of my independent variable from my questionnaire (it consist of 8 variables, meaning that 8 questions are testing for this one particular independent variable).

I would like to adjust my number of variables to only 5, so do I keep using Cronbach's Alpha until I get the most coherent 5 variables? (Meaning that compute 8 inside and then remove 1, and compute 7 inside and remove 1 again, until I get the most coherent 5.)

Comment: That's an interesting question. I have taken the liberty of editing your question, and hope that I have retained your intended meaning.